# How to make Xscreensaver not load while Brave Browser runs videos

Tags: screensaver, xscreensaver

I'm running Ubuntu over ARM (RPi4), and I have XScreenSaver installed.

The screensaver loads while Brave Browser plays Youtube videos. It doesn't load while VLC is running videos, though.

---

XScreenSaver's wiki says that Chromium browsers should handle this by themselves: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XScreenSaver

Does anyone know what I should do to block XScreenSaver to start when any media is running?